# ElevatedButton onPressed not working after Offset with Transform.translate

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use Transform.translate to offset buttons radially from a central point on the screen. However, in the example below, button 'A' does not work, yet button 'B' does work. I read up a little bit about how the parent widget and button need to overlap for the button to work, however, I'm new to flutter and I don't really understand how to resolve it in my case here.

[image: I've attached a screenshot of the example app]

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

//Function to convert to degree to radians
double getRadianFromDegree(double degree) {
  double unitRadian = 57.295779513;
  return degree / unitRadian;
}


void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
    theme: new ThemeData(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.teal[100]),
    home: Home()));



class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Test"),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal[600],
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              left: 175,
              bottom: 200,
              right: 0,
              child: Stack(children: <Widget> [
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadianFromDegree(-90), 130),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {print("A works");},
                    child: Text("A"),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      primary: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadianFromDegree(0), 130),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {print("B works");},
                    child: Text("B"),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      primary: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

              ]),
            )]),
        ));
  }
}
```

Edit: The end goal is to create an arrangement of buttons like this. Manually positioning each button requires too much trial and error to achieve a perfect circle. Ideally, I'd like to keep the Transform.translate and solve the button response issue.
[image: End Goal]

Comment: use `Positioned`, not `Transform.translate`

Comment: I need them to be arranged radially, the final product will have more buttons, but the purpose of this example is to make the buttons function using Transform.translate. I can't use Positioned to perfect arrange buttons in a circle.

Comment: *"I can't use Positioned to perfect arrange buttons in a circle"* - yes, you can, just use right `left` and `top` properties

Comment: also check https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27587 for more info about strange things that `Transform` widget can make

Comment: but honestly if you really want to make a complex layout (like circular) then use `CustomMultiChildLayout` class - the docs say: *"CustomMultiChildLayout is appropriate when there are complex relationships between the size and positioning of multiple widgets."*